# Open a JSON files and edit structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

I have produced a couple of json files after scraping a few elements. The structure for each file is as follows:

us.json

```
{'Pres': 'Biden', 'Vice': 'Harris', 'Secretary': 'Blinken'}
```

uk.json

```
{'1st Min': 'Johnson', 'Queen':'Elizabeth', 'Prince': 'Charles'}
```

I'd like to know how I could edit the structure of each dictionary inside the json file to get an output as it follows:

```
[
    {"title": "Pres",
    "name": "Biden"}
    ,

    {"title": "Vice",
    "name": "Harris"}
    ,
     {"title": "Secretary",
    "name": "Blinken"}
]
```

As far as I am able to think how to do it (I'm a beginner, studying only since a few weeks) I need first to run a loop to open each file, then I should generate a list of dictionaries and finally modify the dictionary to change the structure. This is what I got NOT WORKING as it overrides always with the same keys.

```
import os
import json

list_of_dicts = []
for filename in os.listdir("DOCS/Countries Data"):
    with open(os.path.join("DOCS/Countries Data", filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        country_json = json.loads(text)
        list_of_dicts.append(country_json)
        for country in list_of_dicts:
            newdict = country
            lastdict = {}
        for key in newdict:
            lastdict = {'Title': key}
        for value in newdict.values():
            lastdict['Name'] = value
            print(lastdict)
```

Extra bonus if you could also show me how to generate an ID mumber for each entry. Thank you very much

Comment: Look at `json.dumps` and optional argument `indent` https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html for the pretty indenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This look like task for `list` *comprehension*, I would do it following way

```
import json
us = '{"Pres": "Biden", "Vice": "Harris", "Secretary": "Blinken"}'
data = json.loads(us)
us2 = [{"title":k,"name":v} for k,v in data.items()]
us2json = json.dumps(us2)
print(us2json)
```

output

```
[{"title": "Pres", "name": "Biden"}, {"title": "Vice", "name": "Harris"}, {"title": "Secretary", "name": "Blinken"}]
```

`data` is `dict`, `.items()` provide key-value pairs, which I unpack into `k` and `v` (see *tuple unpacking*).

Comment: Nice, I see the logic. It's great for keep learning, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I got this "extra" characters (\ and ") inside the dictionary after dumping the output into a json file

[{\"title\": \"Pres.\", \"name\": \"Biden\"}, {\"title\": \"Vice\", \"name\": \"Harris\"}, {\"title\": \"Secretary\", \"name\": \"Binklen\"}]

Any idea why?

Comment: @arkanjie did not you dumped to JSON twice?

Comment: Yap, you're right. I fixed, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by writing a simple function like below

```
import uuid
def format_dict(data: dict):
    return [dict(title=title, name=name, id=str(uuid.uuid4())) for title, name in data.items()]
```

where you can split the items as different objects and add a identifier for each using `uuid`.

Full code can be modified like this

```
import uuid
import os
import json

def format_dict(data: dict):
    return [dict(title=title, name=name, id=str(uuid.uuid4())) for title, name in data.items()]

list_of_dicts = []
for filename in os.listdir("DOCS/Countries Data"):
    with open(os.path.join("DOCS/Countries Data", filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        country_json = json.load(f)
        list_of_dicts.append(format_dict(country_json))

# list_of_dicts contains all file contents
```

Comment: lovely! I'm still far to be able to build my functions but your example will help me for you. Thanks a lot for contributing with such a great example